# Error while Connecting my-sql client with Django in Mac

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have got an error: “Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0_/7l07f2kd7gs4679qlmr5nvym0000gn/T/pip-install-j0dudxeq/mysqlclient/”

While installing mysqlclient with python 3

Comment: you have to install mysql in mac

Comment: Thus what I am asking. I am getting the error while run pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this installing libmysqlclient-dev first:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: OP is not using ubuntu.

Comment: try this `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: I am getting the error while run pip install mysqlclient

Comment: `pip install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Install mysqlclient from the pip:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Or if you have python3, pip3 would work for you:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I am getting the error while run pip install mysqlclient